# How to display the additional set of data on click on button in angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a get api that is giving response for data to load. The problem here is if i am getting like 25 results from the api I should display only 9 results on first load which i have implemented like this. But here the problem here is I should have show more button when i click on that it should show the next 9 results and the remaining should be displayed on again click of show more but i am confused how will i implement this and how will i know these much data is already displayed. And in addition while the last set of data is loaded i should display show less button. Can anyone help?

```
if (response.length > 8) {
    this.resultList = response.slice(0, 8);
    this.isShowMore = true;
  }
  else {
    this.resultList = response;
    this.isShowMore = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in an easy solution using showLess showMore methods that deal pageLimit variable.

Also, I think you can use the npm package that helps you if you need to do something like scrolling pagination

[ngx-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div>
  <h3> {{title}}</h3>
  <ul class="list">
      <li *ngFor="let l of list | slice : startPage:paginationLimit">{{l.name}} ({{l.age}})</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="show-more-btn" *ngIf ="paginationLimit < list.length" (click)="showMoreItems()">Show More</button>
  <button class="show-more-btn" *ngIf ="paginationLimit > 3" (click)="showLessItems()">Show Less</button>
</div>

  `,
})
export class App {
   title:String;
  list:any;
  startPage : Number;
  paginationLimit:Number; 
  constructor() {
    this.title = "Angular: Show more/show less pagination";
    this.list = [
      {name:'Prashobh',age:'25'},
      {name:'Abraham',age:'35'},
      {name:'Anil',age:'40'},
      {name:'Sam',age:'40'},
      {name:'Philip',age:'40'},
      {name:'Bal',age:'40'},
      {name:'Anu',age:'20'},
      {name:'Sam',age:'25'},
      {name:'Rocky',age:'35'},
      {name:'Major',age:'40'},
      {name:'Kian',age:'40'},
      {name:'Karan',age:'40'},
      {name:'Bal',age:'40'},
      {name:'Anu',age:'20'},
      {name:'Prashobh',age:'25'},
      {name:'Abraham',age:'35'},
      {name:'Anil',age:'40'},
      {name:'Sam',age:'40'},
      {name:'Philip',age:'40'},
      {name:'Bal',age:'40'},
      {name:'Anu',age:'20'}
    ]
    this.startPage = 0;
    this.paginationLimit = 3;
  }
  showMoreItems()
   {
      this.paginationLimit = Number(this.paginationLimit) + 3;        
   }
   showLessItems()
   {
     this.paginationLimit = Number(this.paginationLimit) - 3;
   }
}
```